# Ignore return outside of function with babel 7

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, babeljs

I recently updated to babel 7 and webpack 4 and am receiving this error when running our gulp build task:

```
gulp build
[00:26:04] Requiring external module @babel/register
[91m[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /node_modules/lodash/lodash.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[0m[91m/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:95
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /node_modules/dev-ip/lib/dev-ip.js: 'return' outside of function (41:8)

  39 |     var out = getIp();
  40 |     if (!out.length) {
> 41 |         return console.log(messages.error);
     |         ^
  42 |     }
  43 |     console.log(getIp("cli"));
  44 | }
    at Parser.raise (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:41:63)
    at Parser.parseReturnStatement (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:577:12)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:199:21)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:146:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:865:25)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:841:10)
    at Parser.parseBlock (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:818:10)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:223:21)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:146:17)
    at Parser.parseIfStatement (/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:570:28)
[0m[91merror Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This is caused by the return outside of a function in browser-syncs dev-ip dependency.

Is there a way to configure my .babelrc file to ignore this?

I've tried the following:

1. Installing only production dependencies, but because browser sync is imported in my gulp file it's still being compiled
2. Setting up workspaces with yarn, but similar issue as #1
3. Dynamically importing browser sync in my gulp file, I guess this is not yet supported yet?
4. Telling babel to ignore or exclude compiling the node_modules folder, but this doesn't seem to do anything?

Apparently babel-parser has an option `allowReturnOutsideFunction: true`, but I can't figure out how to set this in my .babelrc file.

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: Why do you have a `return` that's no in a function in the first place? What is it supposed to be translated to?

Comment: I don't have a return outside of a function, one of my dependencies does :(

Comment: That's weird, I can't think of a reason why any library would do that. Are you sure you downloaded it correctly?

Comment: Never mind, I just found the github, it actually does that.

Comment: I can't see how that's ever supposed to work when run natively, and naturally babel can't figure out what to do with it, either.

Comment: I'm debating forking browser-sync or just removing it from our task runner altogether and rewriting with webpack dev server

Comment: I think you could just remove that block of code. It only runs when you run `dev-ip.js` as the main script, not when you require it as a library.

Comment: The block beginning with `if (require.main == module)`

Comment: @Barmar I think this question is specifically about how to ignore this Babel parser error in a dependency of a dependency.

Comment: @cubrr I understand that's the question, but I doubt there's a way to do that. Even if you can hide the error, it still doesn't know how to transpile the code.

Comment: I don't think removing the block of code will work as this error is being thrown inside our docker container and that would require writing some serious hacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find a solution to this, I ended up just forking browser-sync and dev-ip.

I give you, [browser-stink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-stink)

Answer (score 2):

With Babel7, you can provide all [parser options](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser#options) (which include `allowReturnOutsideFunction`) via [`parserOpts`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#parseropts), e.g.:

```js
// .babelrc.js
module.exports = {
  parserOpts: { allowReturnOutsideFunction: true }
};
```